# The javascript sidebar is not working when i use a IFRAME

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I'm using a lot of javascript here and am unable to detect the problem with few things.
Please go through this page first :

You can see a sidebar which i'm using for "NEWS".
The problem is that when i use a "i frame" html tag to embed another page, the sidebar i.e the news column disappears.
You can check it out at :

I want the sidebar to be perfectly working even after i use the iframe.
Please help me sort this issue out.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall close the iframe tag:

```
<iframe ...></iframe>
```

Comment: lol...such a simple one...seriously apologize for wastin your time..but seriously thankful :) Cheers mate !! :)

Answer (score 0):

forgot to insert `<div id="sidebar">...</div>` ? :)